# Looping through in vba to get proper result

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a Excel result in a proper format but I am so confused in the looping and the condition and tried all night long and still not able to figure it out.

Easy structure but complex coding, If possible it would be better if the code is VBscript friendly.

Actual table from the code below:

> ```
>      E1    E2   E1
> ABC  P     F
> Xyz  P     P
> ```

Output table expected is:

> ```
>      E1    E2
> ABC  P     F
> PQR  F     P
> Xyz  P     P
> ```

Text file: I have 6 of these files

> ```
> Env>E1
> TestName>ABC
> Result>P
> ```

Below is the code:

```
    Public Sub Temp()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1:D10").ClearContents
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   Set MyObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\looping\xmlfile")
   For Each file In MySource.Files
     If InStr(file.Name, "txt") > 0 Then
       'myFile = file.Path
       fileSpec = file.Path '"C:\Prac_Session\OLB.xml" 'change the path to whatever yours ought to be
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
    rowupdate = 1
    colupdate = 1
    Open fileSpec For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
            ''debug.Print textline
                If InStr(textline, "TestName>") > 0 Then 'Read line by line and store all lines in strContents
                    For rw = 2 To 4
                        If Sheet1.Cells(rw, 1) <> Mid(textline, 10, Len(textline) - 9) Then
                            If Sheet1.Cells(rw, 1) = "" Then
                                Sheet1.Cells(rw, 1).Value = Mid(textline, 10, Len(textline) - 9)
                                rowupdate = rw
                                Exit For
                            ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(rw, 1) = Mid(textline, 10, Len(textline) - 9) Then
                                rowupdate = rw
                                Exit For
                            ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(rw, 1) <> Mid(textline, 10, Len(textline) - 9) Then
                                Sheet1.Cells(rw + 1, 1) = Mid(textline, 10, Len(textline) - 9)
                                 rowupdate = rw
                                 Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                If InStr(textline, "Env>") > 0 Then 'Read line by line and store all lines in strContents
                    For col = 2 To 3
                        If Sheet1.Cells(1, col) <> Mid(textline, 5, Len(textline) - 4) Then
                            If Sheet1.Cells(1, col) = "" Then
                                Sheet1.Cells(1, col).Value = Mid(textline, 5, Len(textline) - 4)
                                colupdate = col
                                Exit For
                            ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(1, col).Value = Mid(textline, 5, Len(textline) - 4) Then
                                colupdate = col
                                Exit For
                            ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(1, col) <> Mid(textline, 5, Len(textline) - 4) Then
                                Sheet1.Cells(1, col + 1) = Mid(textline, 5, Len(textline) - 4)
                                colupdate = col
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                If InStr(textline, "Result>") > 0 Then 'Read line by line and store all lines in strContents
                    Sheet1.Cells(rowupdate, colupdate).Value = Mid(textline, 8, Len(textline) - 7)
                    rowupdate = 1
                    colupdate = 1
                End If
    Loop
    Close #1
  End If
  Next file
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i said in the first line "i am trying to get excel result in proper format"

Comment: What is your code doing that is in error?

Comment: no error as such, just the acutal output is not in a proper format, i just need a guidence in the looping? Let me edit the acutal output that i recieved from this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,i got it!!!!. This is resolved now. Thanks.

```
Public Sub Temp()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1:D10").ClearContents
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
Set MyObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\looping\xmlfile")
rowupdate = 2
colupdate = 2
For Each file In MySource.Files
 If InStr(file.Name, "txt") > 0 Then
   'myFile = file.Path
   fileSpec = file.Path '"C:\Prac_Session\OLB.xml" 'change the path to whatever yours ought to be
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)

Open fileSpec For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
        ''debug.Print textline
    spltext = Split(textline, ">")
    Select Case spltext(0)
        Case "TestName"
            Set searchtext = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A1000").Find(spltext(1), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not searchtext Is Nothing Then
            rowspl = Split(searchtext.Address, "$")
                lrow = rowspl(2) 'Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Sheet1.Cells(lrow, 1) = spltext(1)
            Else
                Sheet1.Cells(rowupdate, 1) = spltext(1)
                lrow = rowupdate
            End If
        Case "Env"
            Set searchtext = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(spltext(1), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not searchtext Is Nothing Then
                colspl = Split(searchtext.Address, "$")
                lcol = colspl(1) 'Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Sheet1.Range(lcol & "1") = spltext(1)
            Else
                Sheet1.Cells(1, colupdate) = spltext(1)
                lcol = colupdate
            End If
        Case "Result"
            If lcol = "0" Or lcol = "1" Or lcol = "2" Or lcol = "3" Or lcol = "4" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(lrow, lcol) = spltext(1)
            rowupdate = rowupdate + 1
            colupdate = colupdate + 1
            Else
            Sheet1.Range(lcol & "" & lrow).Value = spltext(1)
            'rowupdate = rowupdate + 1
            'colupdate = colupdate + 1
            End If
    End Select
Loop
Close #1
End If
Next file
End Sub
```